# Contemporary synonym of "thereanent" or "thereabout"

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary, adverbs, archaicisms

I want to express that one thing concerns another, using an adverb, such as in:

> I mended the sink and wrote her a note *thereanent* / *thereabout*.

Meaning:

> I mended the sink and wrote her a note *about that*.

I've done a quick internet research, which yielded the following results:

- *Thereanent* is a term of Scottish origin, and apparently not in common use today, so it's very likely to be understood only by a small group of people [[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thereanent), [2](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thereanent), [3](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thereanent), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34581/are-older-senses-of-anent-still-alive-in-any-dialect/115460#115460)].
- The usage of *thereabout* in this sense is considered archaic. However, it is rather commonly used today, in the same sense as *thereabouts*, which has other meanings: *near that place or time*; and *approximately that number or amount*. Therefore, it is likely to be misinterpreted or cause confusion when used with the same meaning as *thereanent* [[5](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thereabout), [6](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thereabout)].

Is there a contemporary synonym of *thereanent* or *thereabout*?

Comment: You might get away with ***thereof*** in your context, but many/most of these single-word ***there + [preposition]*** forms have fallen into disuse (and I never knew of ***thereanent*** anyway). The natural form today is just *...wrote her a note **about it***.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603965/2085).